# UKVI made a mistake on my entry clearance decision

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

The UKVI decision making centre in Istanbul made a mistake on my entry clearance, and my fiance and I ended up getting a refusal letter. At the back of the refusal letter, it's written that I don't have a right to appeal however I want to get in touch with them and ask them to reassess my application.

My Questions:

1. How can I submit my reassess request? letter or email?
2. Who should I address?
3. How do you find my drafted letter that I am going to send to the authorities? (see the last letter)
4. When communicating with the independent inspector, should I call these a mistake or a misinterpretation from UKVI?

Here is brief information about us:

- I am holding a temporary residence in Turkey rather than my home country since 2 years ago.
- I am working for a British Organisation since 3 years ago.
- In Feb 2018, my fiance and I applied to visit the UK for 9 days in March 2018.
- My residence permit is due to expire in August 2018 however due to local immigration policies I am not allowed to apply for the extension 60 days before the resident permit expires.
- My net income salary per annum is EUR 45600.
- I had previously been issued with a UK visa and we have been granted a Schengen visit visa in the past. together we travelled to 4 different countries in 2017.

UKVI DMC Istanbul mistakes:

- ECO tried to confirm my hotel booking, but later they found out it was cancelled. (the reason for the cancellation is explained in my letter. ) however,  they strongly advise not to confirm the travel arrangements until we have received our visa. (it was printed on several papers in VAC and as shown in here http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/uae/frequently_asked_questions.html)
- They didn't contact my employer to confirm my employment status and if they are willing to extend or not.
- ECO noted a factual error regarding my residence permit.
- ECO noted that my fiance is employed, but she is not.
- I have declared that I would fund all travel expenses for my fiancé, but they subjected that it will be at her costs and she can’t afford the trip.

UKVI refused us a visit visa with the following refusal letter:

[My Refusal Letter page 1[image: My Refusal Letter page 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5raf5.jpg)
[My Refusal Letter page 2[image: My Refusal Letter Page 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgMP9.jpg)

And this is the refusal letter for my fiance.

[My fiance's refusal letter page 1[image: My fiance's refusal letter page 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9je0y.jpg)
[My fiance's refusal letter page 2[image: My fiance's refusal letter page 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc9sw.jpg)
[Here is the letter that I want to send to the DMC, independent inspector and British Embassy in Ankara and the consulate in Istanbul[image: enter image description here![letter to DMC]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPvQJ.jpg)

Comment: What is the mistake?

Comment: If it was a blatant mistake, try emailing the issuing UKVI hub, the Embassy in your country and the independent chief inspector of Borders and Immigration. The UKVI's decision making at some hubs is dismal as shown by independent inspections.

Comment: Please post the refusal letter with your personal details blanked out, and explain the mistake. You may find people on this site would recommend a new application instead, depending on the situation.

Comment: I have added new information to the question including the refusal letter and the letter that I am going to send out to the DMC, inspector and the embassy. please have a look at them. 

Quick question, when submitting a new application, do I need to also submit a letter explaining their previous mistakes(or incorrect judgment)?

Comment: @Shayan "Quick question, when submitting a new application, do I need to also submit a letter explaining their previous mistakes(or incorrect judgment)?"

Absolutely, in every single detail with every piece of evidence you can provide

Comment: That's a very good letter that you have drafted. Do send a copy to the independent inspector of borders and immigration. (https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/independent-chief-inspector-of-borders-and-immigration) Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: I know my ground of refusal. I want to know how to object them.

Comment: You could have avoided at least 2 of the refusal reasons if you’d put yourself in the ECO’s shoes when you compiled your application. Providing evidence of your contract extension and the information about renewing your residence permit upfront would have been helpful - I doubt ECOs have the time to check out every aspect of an application, the onus is on the applicant to explain their circumstances in full.