# Complaint procedure for visit visa to UK 6 month

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistan

Can the sponsor or applicant make a complaint for the decision of visit visa to UK for 6 months ?

What is the procedure or link to do that ?

Comment: [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking) explains why you were refused and how to reapply in order to get approved for the visa.

Comment: You were refused UK visas in 2016 and 2017. I think the only reasonable suggestion is to get a competent and recognized immigration solicitor otherwise you’re not going to the UK soon, maybe ever.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It should be reopened. It is a different question and has a totally different answer from the linked alleged duplicate.

Comment: i edited the question to delete the Refusal Image for privacy reasons. But someone re added it. Kindly delete the refusal image.

Answer (score 12):

Nope, there is no standard procedure to appeal or complaint against a standard visitor visa refusal for UK.

Refusal letters [clearly say](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110678/ukvi-made-a-mistake-on-my-entry-clearance-decision):

> In relation to this decision there is no right of appeal or right to administrative review.

Answer (score 11):

Generally, there is no right of appeal for visit visa applications. However, that does not mean that ECO's have no accountability. You still have two options:

- **Ask the ECM for a review**. If there is an obvious error made by the ECO (such as reading the numbers on the application form wrong), the ECM will be able to overturn the ECO's decision. My friend was successfully able to do this. In the refusal notice, the ECO had referred to parts of the application which were materially different from what was actually stated.
- **Judicial review**. If you believe there has been an error of law, such as not following the proper procedure, you could be able to get the decision quashed through a judicial review. However, you would need a solicitor and be prepared to bear the expenses. Normally, a second application would be a better choice.

Depending on why you think the decision was wrong, you should also contact the British Embassy/High Commission in your country, the decision making hub, the independent inspector for the UKVI, and any other relevant bodies that you think could make a difference.

**Edit:** The OP has posted a copy of the refusal notice. While the refusal may appear unfair, I don't think the remedies above will help him much. The ECO is concerned about the two large deposits in the OP's account and while the ECO does not outright accuse the OP of deception, he thinks the documents submitted cannot be considered evidence. The burden of proof is on the applicant. He has to prove he qualifies.

A second application would be the way to go. To show the origin of these funds and depending on what exactly was sold the OP could produce:

- copies of the cheques used
- vehicle registration documents (in case of a car)
- property transfer/registration documents
- any other documents that can be verified independently

Comment: People are downvoting this without mentioning what they believe is wrong with a perfectly reasonable answer. Sad.

Comment: _One_ person is not "people". (It wasn't me.)

Comment: This is a good answer. I see no reason for a down-vote

Comment: It is a good answer. I'd add that this is most likely to help in a situation where the ECO blatantly and obviously screwed something up (such as the times we've seen [blank template refusal notices](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93879/uk-visa-blank-refusal-letter-without-reason-for-refusal) when the immigration rules say you're supposed to get a filled in one) or your file has clearly gotten mixed up with someone else's. "An obvious error" in this case is a procedural error where the rules weren't followed, not simply disagreeing with the ECO's conclusions.

Comment: It would also help to know how to contact the ECM, since they make pretty strong efforts to ring-fence the visa operation to keep people from bothering them and make everyone go through VFS.

Comment: @Zach Lipton email the embassy, the UKVI on their helpline and if they think it's important it will get to the ECM. If they don't reply there is always regular mail. Or if you have the means, hire a solicitor to do it for you. I also want to add since OP is from Pakistan, UKVI's independent inspector concluded that decisions against Pakistanis are quite often unfair. You can Google the report.

Comment: @Honorary World Citizen ehmm... Looks like it did help

Answer (score 6):

You can NOT ask for a review because your application is excluded from review per the link below.

[Ask for a visa administrative review](https://www.gov.uk/ask-for-a-visa-administrative-review)

> **If you're outside the UK**
>
> You’ll be told in your application refusal letter if you can ask for
>   the decision on your visa application to be reviewed. This is known as
>   an ‘administrative review’.
>
> You can only ask for an administrative review if all of the following
>   apply:
>
> - you’re outside the UK
> - you applied outside the UK
> - your application was refused on or after 6 April 2015
> - you don’t have a right of appeal against the refusal
> - **you didn’t make an application as a visitor or a short term student**
>
> **How to apply**
>
> You must apply for an administrative review within 28 days of getting
>   the decision.
>
> You’ll either get the administrative review application form with your
>   application refusal letter, or you’ll be asked to download it.
>
> When you get the form you must:
>
> - enter the reasons for refusal that are on your decision letter, and say why you think a mistake was made
> - send your completed form in the method the application refusal letter suggests (by email, post or in person)
>
> The guidance notes tell you how to fill in the administrative review
>   application form.

Comment: Did you intend this as an answer to OP's question, or as general info? As the visa was for the visitor visa, you might want to say that *No* they can't, and add emphasis to the last bullet point: ***you didn’t make an application as a visitor or a short term student***

Comment: @Warda123 The MP won't talk to the ECO, they will write to a Home Office minister, who might make enquiries with the ECO. Either way, it's unlikely to help.