# Was my UK visit visa refused?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, application-status, ghanaian-citizens

I am Ghanaian I applied for a UK visitor visa and, today, I received my passport without a UK visa in it. No letter was attached to the passport, either. What should I do?

Comment: The letter of approval or refusal arrives separately.

Comment: You will find out soon.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Does the letter include the visa itself? Everyone I’ve known who has had their UK visa approved has received their passport back with the visa attached inside

Comment: @Traveller No, the visa, if approved, would be in the passport. But this person might also have asked for their documents to be returned before the visa decision has been made, which is an option for some countries. In that case they'll have to bring the passport back to get the visa affixed.

Comment: @ Micheal Hampton I never asked of my passport to be returned ..That was the decision they took after 15 working days of submitting.SO DO I CONTACT THEM AND ASK OF THE REASON FOR REFUSAL?

Answer (score 1):

Wait for a few more days, if you do not receive the explanation/refusal notice separately contact them for it.

Sometimes these ECO’s make mistakes, overlook things or maybe your application got lost somewhere in the supply chain and your passport returned without being reviewed.It happens.

Of course if they do give you a reason and you are not satisfied you can follow the procedure outlined in [Complaint procedure for visit visa to UK 6 month](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124278/complaint-procedure-for-visit-visa-to-uk-6-month/124282#124282)